# Need to re-write url Sub-domain to non-existing folder not redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have tried different situations, but it didn't work

I have a WordPress site on sub-domain ***abc.domain.com*** .
Path of which folder created on server is like in this form "abc.domain.com"

Now I want it displayed as "***domain.com/abc***", also when user types in browser "abc.domain.com" browser should display "***domain.com/abc***". Also search engines should display "***domain.com/abc***"

**Note**- there is no folder name "abc" (subdomain folder name is abc.domain.com where all files located)

Please help me in doing it.

Here's what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /abc/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a symbolic link `abc.domain.com -> abc`
2. Change Wordpress permalink to change site and home URL to `domain.com/abc`